# Why does the space have no effect in this line of my code?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\begin{document}

Number $2-a$:

\begin{align*}
Z &\longleftarrow \Phi(x,x) \\
Y &\longleftarrow Y +1
\end{align*}
Number $2-b$:
      \begin{align*}
IF x &\in A    GOTO E\\
Z &\longleftarrow \Phi(x,x) \\
Y &\longleftarrow Y +1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

And it looks like this (the problem is the red-circled line):

[image]

What should I do to make that line look like this where it looks more like handwriting where words are separated:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In math-mode spaces are ignored. (`align` as well as `align*`, `equation` etc. automatically swith to math-mode.) Just test `$a b$`: no space inside in the output. If you want to have spaces in math-mode, you could use explicit space (e.g. `\␣` (slash space) or `\hspace{1em}`), but to get correct kerning and roman instead of italics format you should switch to text mode, i.e.

```
\text{IF }x&\in\text{A    GOTO E}
```

The `\text` command is supplied by the [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package which you already load anyway. Between `A` and `GOTO` there will be only one regular space, if more is needed the `\hspace{1em}` (in text mode!) could be used there.

Comment: Do _not_ just insert a space with `\ `. Letters in math mode are typeset as if they are variables being multiplied, so if you use it for regular text you get terribly spaced italics.

Comment: Sorry, "better" suggests that both approaches are correct, but formatting _any_ word in math mode is wrong. `\text` doesn't just switch to roman, it also fixes the kerning; which is why `\text{\it sufficient}` looks much better than $sufficient$.

Comment: @alexis: I hope I got it right with the edit this time.

Comment: @Stephen You can use `<code>\&nbsp;</code>`, `<code>\ </code>`, or (in this case maybe even preferred) `\␣` to get the space shown up in your output.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Done & thank you! When I continue with editing like that, this will get CW soon...

Comment: @Stephen You have some edits left! ;) (`\␣` can still be codified with `, btw.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Well, then: edited again. :-)

Answer (score 10):

use

```
\text{IF }x &\in\text{ A    GOTO E}\\
```

spaces in math mode have no effect.

Comment: OK, you were 34 seconds faster :-) therefore +1.

Answer (score 5):

In math mode, every element of text is assumed to be a variable, and typeset as such : in particular, for this matter, variables shouldn't form "words", that's why the texing engine won't display spaces. However, it is possible to print text "as if non in math mode", but you have to tell latex that it should regard that content as text.

Amongst the various commands you may use :

- `\mathrm`, `\mathbf`, etc (for mathematical text, such as function names : this won't give correct spacing as well!)
- `\text` from the `amsmath` package (for casual text, will use the font of the outer environment)
- `\textrm`, `\textbf`, etc. (in case you need specific font formatting -- the difference with the math equivalent is that you can use accented characters or inline maths inside these)

In your example, this works, for example :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Number $2-a$:

\begin{align*}
Z &\longleftarrow \Phi(x,x) \\
Y &\longleftarrow Y +1
\end{align*}
Number $2-b$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{IF } x &\in A \mathbf{ GOTO } E\\
Z &\longleftarrow \Phi(x,x) \\
Y &\longleftarrow Y +1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note that as I said above, spaces are basically ignored in math display. So if you want your spaces to be taken into account, and your text to be separated from the rest of the sentence, you need to make sure the spaces are with the text, inside the braces.